# How to add trend line to high charts

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

This is the high chart graph code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            title: {
                text: 'RNA',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Outage Reasons',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['18-Jul-14', '19-Jul-14', '20-Jul-14', '21-Jul-14', '22-Jul-14', '23-Jul-14',
                    '24-Jul-14', '25-Jul-14', '26-Jul-14', '27-Jul-14', '28-Jul-14', '29-Jul-14']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Outage'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ''
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'RNA - CP ( Radio Network Availability - Customer Perceived)',
                data: [99.75, 99.77, 99.78, 99.84, 99.82, 99.82, 99.76, 99.78, 99.8, 99.65, 99.94, 99.8]
            }],
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            }
        });
    });


        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<script src="highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

I want to add trend line for this chart, i searched in google and got the code from this link : https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/highcharts_trendline 
and i added the trend line code like this .

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

         <script type="text/javascript" src="regression.js"></script>

          <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            title: {
                text: 'RNA',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Outage Reasons',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['18-Jul-14', '19-Jul-14', '20-Jul-14', '21-Jul-14', '22-Jul-14', '23-Jul-14',
                    '24-Jul-14', '25-Jul-14', '26-Jul-14', '27-Jul-14', '28-Jul-14', '29-Jul-14']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Outage'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ''
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'RNA - CP ( Radio Network Availability - Customer Perceived)',
                data: [99.75, 99.77, 99.78, 99.84, 99.82, 99.82, 99.76, 99.78, 99.8, 99.65, 99.94, 99.8]
            }],
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            }
        });
    });


     var sourceData = [
          [18-Jul-14, 99.75], [19-Jul-14, 99.77],
          [20-Jul-14, 99.78], [21-Jul-14, 99.84],
          [22-Jul-14, 99.82], [23-Jul-14, 99.82],
          [24-Jul-14, 99.76], [25-Jul-14, 99.78],
          [26-Jul-14, 99.8], [27-Jul-14, 99.65],
          [28-Jul-14, 99.94], [29-Jul-14, 99.8]
      ];

      var chart_linear = new highcharts.Chart({
          chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
          },
          plotOptions: {
            series: {
              enableMouseTracking: false
            }
          },
          series: [{
            type: 'scatter',
            data: sourceData
          },
          {
            type: 'line',
            marker: { enabled: false },
            /* function returns data for trend-line */
            data: (function() {
              return fitData(sourceData).data;
            })()
          }]
      });


        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

<script src="exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

and the trend line that acts according to the x-axis and y-axis values but on the x-axis values are date wise and the y-axis values are numbers ,please find the screen shot for the first code :
[image]

And this the trend line snapshot. please find.
[image]

please share any one of the code that i would like to add the two graphs in the same page , i have tried but the x-axis and y-axis values are different for the two graphs.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you replicate your example as live demo on jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Here's an answer where I show the math involved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115693/how-to-create-an-average-line-for-an-irregular-time-graph/22119019#22119019

Comment: yes m ihave already seen the above link but it is different from my code.

Comment: other wise , any one can make changes in the code that i got  trend line from this link : https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/highcharts_trendline    from this link i have downloaded the 'demo.html' and implementing but in this for x-axis and y-axis values are required but the line should draw according to the y-axis value.

Comment: John, it is different from your code, that's the math that `regression.js` is using.  I'm using this as a teaching moment, instead of you cutting and pasting from links across the internet, take a moment and learn the math, then implement for yourself.  This is how to become a great developer.  Regardless, I fixed your code below :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Numerous problems.

1.) You didn't really integrate the regresssion code into your plot, you just cut/pasted from the example and are over-drawing your plot.  You need to add the regression line as a second series to your plot:

```
        series: [{
            name: 'RNA - CP ( Radio Network Availability - Customer Perceived)',
            data: sourceData
        },{
            type: 'line',
            marker: { enabled: false },
            /* function returns data for trend-line */
            data: (function() {
              return fitData(sourceData).data;
            })()
        }]
```

2.) This is not valid javascript:

```
 var sourceData = [
      [18-Jul-14, 99.75], [19-Jul-14, 99.77],
      [20-Jul-14, 99.78], [21-Jul-14, 99.84],
      [22-Jul-14, 99.82], [23-Jul-14, 99.82],
      [24-Jul-14, 99.76], [25-Jul-14, 99.78],
      [26-Jul-14, 99.8], [27-Jul-14, 99.65],
      [28-Jul-14, 99.94], [29-Jul-14, 99.8]
  ];
```

Those are strings and they aren't quoted.  Regardless, strings won't cut it for the regression, it needs numbers.  Since your dates are really categories, just use:

```
 var sourceData = [
      [0, 99.75], [1, 99.77],
      [2, 99.78], [3, 99.84],
      [4, 99.82], [5, 99.82],
      [6, 99.76], [7, 99.78],
      [8, 99.8], [9, 99.65],
      [10, 99.94], [11, 99.8]
  ];
```

3.) Your series name is way too long for a right side legend (it squished the plot).  In my example I moved it to the bottom.

Here's a [example](http://jsfiddle.net/9r9ba64r/) putting all this together.

Comment: Thanks for the code which is very useful and also the math is very perfect , i will learn as soon as possible , as i am new to implement the code in the high charts recently. thanks and thank you very much

Comment: HI mark , can you please explain the code in the sourcecode contains the two values for the X-axis and Y-axis  for the x-axis the values are from 0 to 11 u have taken , it counts the values in the graph for the trend line.

Comment: @John, linear regression (trend line fit) requires both x and y values.  You can not use "string" x values.  Since your dates are  categories internally `Highcharts` is placing them at positions 0, 1, 2, 3, etc...

Comment: hi, The values are internally taking for the X-axis as dates through Highcharts and these values are pointing to the 0,1,2,.....and the Trend line is pointing according to the 18-Jul-2014 = 0, 19-Jul-2014 = 1 ..... .. . .. . and plotting according to the X-axis values 0,1,2,....   and Y-axis values = 99.2,98.9 ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [Plugin](https://rawgit.com/laff/technical-indicators/master/technical-indicators.src.js) that I believe will do what you want to.

```js
$(function() {

    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function(data) {
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

            title : {
                text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
            },

            subtitle: {
                text: 'From may 15, 2006 to May 10, 2013'
            },
            
            xAxis: {
                ordinal: false
            },

            yAxis: {
                title : {
                    text : 'Price'
                }
            },

            legend: {
                enabled: true,
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            
            series : [{
                name: 'Stock Price',
                type : 'line',
                id: 'primary',
                data : data
            }, {
                name: 'Linear Trendline',
                linkedTo: 'primary',
                showInLegend: true,
                enableMouseTracking: false,
                type: 'trendline',
                algorithm: 'linear'
            }]
        });
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/laff/technical-indicators/master/technical-indicators.src.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 500x; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Source:
http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/16/technical-indicators