# how to display chart in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, charts, highcharts

could you please tell me how to add trendlines in highcharts or target lines hight chart .I am able to achieve to draw in **fusion chart** .
.
http://jsfiddle.net/Tu57h/139/
please see above  fiddle link in this developer use **trendlines** .I need same thing in high chart can we draw trend line in high chart

I try to make same thing in hight chart .I got little bit success but not able to make **trendlines** in hight chart 
here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ogwsL7j3/1/

I need to add breadlines in my chart using highcharts

can we show show trend line same as shown in image.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'areaspline'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Average fruit consumption during one week'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'left',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: 250,
            y: 300,
            floating: true,
            borderWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'Monday',
                'Tuesday',
                'Wednesday',
                'Thursday',
                'Friday',
                'Saturday',
                'Sunday'
            ]
        },
        yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        labels: {
            enabled:false
        }
    },

        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            valueSuffix: ' units'
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            areaspline: {
                fillOpacity: 0.8
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 10, 12]
        }]
    });
});
```

any update of this?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907091/does-highcharts-have-a-trend-line-feature

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115693/how-to-create-an-average-line-for-an-irregular-time-graph/22119019#22119019

Comment: I Need straight horizontal tread line as shown in image

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plotLines on yAxis.

```
yAxis: {
        plotLines: [{
            color: '#FF0000',
            width: 2,
            label:{
            text:'trendline',
                align: 'right',
                x: 0
            },
            value: 210
        }]
    },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3zs32jLv/2/